# Easiest way to get element parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose i have this structure of elements:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="something1">
        <div class="something2">
            <div class="something3">
                <div class="something4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

And code like this:

```
$(".something4").click(function(){
   //i could do it like this...
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent();
});
```

But that seems to be stupid, is there a better way to do this?

also i can't just say `$(.parent)` because there are many divs like this with class `parent` in my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use `.parentNode` (standard JavaScript). It's generally a bad idea to use class names that coincide with function/variable names from the library you're using (this goes for any language). Making your class names more unique is a better approach (for instance, "scparent" instead of "parent", if the name of your application was "Super Calculator" or something). This avoids conflicts such as the one you're describing.

I would caution using `.closest()`, simply because you may create a function like this:

```
function getParentElem() {
    return $(this).closest('div');
}
```

And it would grab the parent `div`'s in your code just fine, but if down the road you add a table for displaying data, and you run the function through a child element of the table, you will have to create another implementation that selects the `table` element, because that's what you now want:

```
<div id="tableParent">
    <table id="dataTable">
        <tr id="target1">
            <td>Some data.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

By using your function `getParentElem()` on the `tr` element, you'll end up grabbing the `div` with id="tableParent", rather than the actual parent, which is the `table` element. So, unless you've delineated your parent classes appropriately all the way through your code (which can be a pain and isn't always efficient), you may run into problems. Especially if at any point you're creating elements programmatically, or reading in data from another 3rd-party library or script.

Not saying it's not good to use `.closest()`... just pointing out a possible "gotcha".

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.closest(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). This gets the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
$('.something4').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.parent');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$('.something4').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.parent');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this

```
$(this).parents(".parent");
```

But I don't know where on the page are the other divs with this class :)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest adding to the div parent an id like 'parent_1' etc. and in every son you keep the id in the rel attr

```
<div id="parent_1" class="parent">
    <div rel="1" class="something1">
        <div rel="1" class="something2">
            <div rel="1" class="something3">
                <div rel="1" class="something4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

$(".something4").click(function(){
   //i could do it like this...
   $('#parent_' + $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```